# where to define type annotation while working with HttpClient? ahead to method name or ahead to return block or ahead to response block?

Tags: angular, observable, typescript-typings

I am trying to understand typescript along with Obserbavles with angular 4 setup

version details

```
"@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^4.3.4",
"@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
"rxjs": "^5.1.0"
"@angular/cli": "^1.6.5"
```

### color.service.ts

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

Interface Color {
    code: string;
    name: string;
    stroke?: number;
}

Interface ColorResponse extends Color {
    code: number;
    status: string;
    items: Color[];
}

getColorList(page): <Observable Color[]> {
        let params = new HttpParams();
        params = params.append('page', page);
        return this.httpClient
            .get(`${BASE_URL}/color`, { params: params })
            .map((res) => {
                return res.items;
            });
    }
```

the API response is exactly as following

```
{ 
    code: 200,
    status: 'ok',
    items: [{code: 'fff', name: 'white'}, {code: '000', name: 'black', stroke: 25}]
}
```

BUT above code gives error

> Property 'items' does not exist on type 'Object'.

#### trail 1

set `type (res: any)` => then the error goes away and works fine;

I understand `any` is the type when we are not sure about the response object but does this is the right way or I need to be specific about the response type?

#### trail 2

set `(res: ColorResponse)` and still works fine

so which is the preferred and correct way to write type?

#### trial 3

set `(res: HttpResponse<ColorResponse>)` than it again gives error

So my confusion is where to specify the type exactly?

ahead of the method or ahead of response or ahead of the return

just like `return this.httpClient.get<ColorResponse>`

or do we need to write everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way of specifying the type of response.

```
this.httpClient.get<ColorResponse>
```

Although I'm a bit confused from looking at your code. Is the `ColorResponse` the actual response body, or did you try to model the entire HttpResponse? Because the HttpClient already does `response.json()` behind the scenes to give you the response body

Comment: *ColorResponse* is the interface which map with the response return from `HttpClient.get()`. where I am using `response.json()`

Comment: You don't have to, the HTTP client already does that for you. If you were using the old HTTP module then yes

Comment: so what need to remove. i did not get you.

Comment: Back in Angular 2 version, when using the http module, you would usually have to convert the response to json:


    .map(res => res.json())

This is no longer necessary in Angular 4+, because they introduced a new http client.

Comment: Yes, but where I have written `res.json()`